# How to change a number of rating stars - Magento 1.9.2

Tags: ratings, magento-1.9.2.0

I want to know how to add one star to the rating stars to become five. Im using a **potor** theme.

[image: pic]

Comment: There is no potor theme in magento.. share your Link so giving you proper solution..

Comment: try contact theme developers

Answer (score 0):

There are numbers of extensions out there for star rating in Magento Connect.
Check below link - 
 (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=star+rating&pl=0).

I hope you will find your matching one from there?